# How to setup two-way SSL or mutual authentication between Apache and Wildfly 19 using mod_proxy over https?

Tags: apache, wildfly, mod-proxy

## How to setup two-way SSL or mutual authentication between Apache and Wildfly using mod_proxy over https?

After struggling a bit and couldn't find any documentation online to setup two-way or mutual SSL between Apache Httpd 2.4 and Wildfly 19, so decided to write my own hoping it will help someone. Essentially to securely transmit traffic between apache and wildfly over https.

> **Ref/Courtesy**: Jboss documentation - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/82363. This documentation is heavily based of that but modified it for Wildfly 19 & Elytron SSL Context.

### Environment

- Redhat or Centos 7 or 8
- Wildfly 19
- Apache Httpd 2.4 and Mod_Proxy over Https
- OpenJdk 1.8.0_242 (TLS v1.2).

  > If you need TLS v1.3 use JDK 11 or higher.

### Solution Steps

**Wildfly 19**

**CLI Commands**

```sh
/subsystem=elytron/key-store=MyKeyStore:add(path=/etc/certs/selfSigned/jboss.keystore, credential-reference={clear-text=secret},type=JKS)

/subsystem=elytron/key-manager=MyKeyManager:add(key-store=MyKeyStore,credential-reference={clear-text=secret}})

/subsystem=elytron/key-store=MyKeyTrustStore:add(path=/etc/certs/selfSigned/jboss.truststore, credential-reference={clear-text=secret},type=JKS)

/subsystem=elytron/trust-manager=MyTrustManager:add(key-store=MyKeyTrustStore)

/subsystem=elytron/server-ssl-context=MySSLContext:add(key-manager=MyKeyManager,protocols=["TLSv1.2"],trust-manager=MyTrustManager,need-client-auth=true)

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:add(socket-binding=https, ssl-context=MySSLContext, enable-http2=true)

:reload
```

**Results:**

**Standalone-full.xml**

```xml
. . .
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:8.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
<tls>
    <key-stores>
        <key-store name="MyKeyStore">
            <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
            <implementation type="JKS"/>
            <file path="/etc/certs/selfSigned/jboss.keystore"/>
        </key-store>
        <key-store name="MyKeyTrustStore">
            <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
            <implementation type="JKS"/>
            <file path="/etc/certs/selfSigned/jboss.truststore"/>
        </key-store>
    </key-stores>
    <key-managers>
        <key-manager name="MyKeyManager" key-store="MyKeyStore">
            <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
        </key-manager>
    </key-managers>
    <trust-managers>
        <trust-manager name="MyTrustManager" key-store="MyKeyTrustStore"/>
    </trust-managers>
    <server-ssl-contexts>
        <server-ssl-context name="MySSLContext" protocols="TLSv1.2" need-client-auth="true" key-manager="MyKeyManager" trust-manager="MyTrustManager"/>
    </server-ssl-contexts>
</tls>
</subsystem>

. . .

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.under
tow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">

. . .

 <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="MySSLContext" enable-http2="true"/>

. . .
</subsystem>
```

**Apache Configuration:**

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyTimeout 600

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify On
# For Self Signed Certs with CN name other than localhost
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off

# SSLProxyCACertificateFile - can be either the cert of the JBoss server (when using self-signed certs) 
# or the CA that signed the JBoss cert. 
# If you using actual CA signed cert you don't need to specify SSLProxyCACertificateFile.
SSLProxyCACertificateFile certs/jboss_cert.pem

# SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile - contains the public/private key pair (PEM formatted, concatenated). 
# This is what tells wildfly whether the request is coming a trusted apache. 
# Once again, don't have to specify this if you have an CA signed Cert. Only for Self Generated Certs.
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile certs/apache_proxy.pem


ProxyPass / https://wildfly-localhost:8443/  keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / https://wildfly-localhost:8443/
```

## Script to Generate Self Signed Certs:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

function create_keystore
{
  KEY_FILE=$1
  ALIAS=$2
  DN=$3
  PASS=$4
  keytool -genkey -alias $ALIAS -keyalg RSA -keystore $KEY_FILE -validity 365 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass $PASS -keypass $PASS -dname $DN
}

function export_cert
{
  KEY_FILE=$1
  ALIAS=$2
  EXPORT_FILE=$3
  PASS=$4
  keytool -export -alias $ALIAS -keystore $KEY_FILE -storepass $PASS -file $EXPORT_FILE
}

function import_cert
{
  KEY_FILE=$1
  ALIAS=$2
  IMPORT_FILE=$3
  PASS=$4
  keytool -import -noprompt -alias $ALIAS -keystore $KEY_FILE -storepass $PASS -file $IMPORT_FILE
}

PASSWORD="secret"
APACHE_CN="/C=US/ST=AR/L=Somewhere/CN=apache"

# Use your domain name. example.com
JBOSS_CN="CN=localhost"                                

JBOSS_KEYSTORE="jboss.keystore"
JBOSS_CERT="jboss.cert"
JBOSS_KEY_ALIAS="server"
JBOSS_TRUSTSTORE="jboss.truststore"

echo "Creating public and private keys for Wildfly (Server-side)"

create_keystore $JBOSS_KEYSTORE $JBOSS_KEY_ALIAS $JBOSS_CN $PASSWORD

export_cert $JBOSS_KEYSTORE $JBOSS_KEY_ALIAS $JBOSS_CERT $PASSWORD

echo "Building public/private key to be used with Apache (Client-side)"

#openssl req -x509 -subj $APACHE_CN -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout apache_key.pem -out apache_cert.pem

# Apache Private Key
openssl genrsa -out apache_key.pem 1024
# Apache Cert (Public)
openssl req -new -key apache_key.pem -x509 -subj $APACHE_CN -out apache_cert.pem -days 365
# Apache Combined
cat apache_key.pem apache_cert.pem > apache_proxy.pem

import_cert $JBOSS_TRUSTSTORE "apache" "apache_cert.pem" $PASSWORD

openssl x509 -in $JBOSS_CERT -inform DER -out jboss_cert.pem -outform PEM
```

**Result:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 1253 Apr 15 00:44 apache_cert.pem
-rw------- 1 user root 1679 Apr 15 00:44 apache_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 2932 Apr 15 00:44 apache_proxy.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root  717 Apr 15 00:44 jboss.cert
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 1025 Apr 15 00:44 jboss_cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 2421 Apr 15 00:44 jboss.keystore
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root  948 Apr 15 00:44 jboss.truststore
```

Please feel free to create tickets if you have any issues.
https://github.com/dinbtechit/two-way-ssl-btw-apache-widlfly19-elytron